# Play framework 2.3: "activator" opens browser

Tags: playframework, typesafe-activator

According to https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/Highlights23 "activator" should run the console. Instead it opens the browser (only "activator ui" should do this).

How can i change this?

Answer (score 2):

`activator` will only show you the console if your current directory is a valid project (does not make sense to do it otherwise). If your current directory is a Play project and it opens your browser, then that may be a bug.

Comment: i created the project two minutes before via "activator new"

Comment: And are you able to run `activator compile`, for example?

Comment: Yes, i can run every command except "activator" without parameter. "activator run", "activator compile" and "activator ui" works, for example. "activator" opens the browser. There seems to be a difference between Windows Powershell and the regular command prompt: it works correct via command prompt but not via Powershell. In earlier versions (with play command) it works in both terminals.

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same problem. It appears that this is a bug in activator 2.3.6. Bug is located in activator.bat and is related to detecting doubleclicked execution of that script. I have not found solution how to fix that problem but I have workaround for that. activator.bat is copied locally, so all you need to do is to comment line 48:

```
for %%x in (%cmdcmdline%) do if %%~x==/c set DOUBLECLICKED=1
```

to be

```
rem for %%x in (%cmdcmdline%) do if %%~x==/c set DOUBLECLICKED=1
```

and then run ./activator.bat again.

Comment: Nice, it was exactly my problem, mi activator versión was 1.3.6 though. Thanks a lot mate